# Why does Spock not record calls done by a method of a spied object?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, spock-spy

I am writing an interaction based test with the Help of the Spock Framework, where I would like to check that a method calls another method once.

The class under test looks like this:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
    def a() {
        b()
    }

    def b() {}
}
```

And my test case looks like this

```
class ClassUnderTestTest extends Specification {
    ClassUnderTest cut
    ClassUnderTest spied

    def setup() {
        cut = new ClassUnderTest()
        spied = Spy(cut)
    }

    def "Method a() calls method b()"() {
        when:
        spied.a()

        then:
        1 * spied.a()
        1 * spied.b()
    }
}
```

Running this test, Spock recognises only the call to `a()` but not the call to `b()`.

What did I wrong or what did I miss?

Comment: The example you gave works for me, which version of Spock are you using? Do you have byte-buddy or cglib as dependencies, as these are required for spying on classes.

Comment: I have to check it. My main dependency is jenkins-spock, an extension of Spock to test Jenkins shared libraries and similar stuff.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I updated the dependency from jenkins-spock to `org.spockframework:spock-core` and now it works. If you like, you can suggest this as answer, which I will accept then as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works, make sure you have a recent version of `spock-core` the current version is `2.0-groovy-3.0`, you also need `byte-buddy` to mock classes instead of just interfaces.